# Showing isomorphism of Quotient Ring to direct product of Complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

So I need to prove $$\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^3+1)$$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the field of complex numbers. Based on an example in the book I feel like the answer might have to do with representing the elements of the field using the division algorithm of $\mathbb{C}$, but I'm honestly not sure and don't really now how to start here. Quotient groups tend to be kind of unintuitive for me.

Comment: The quotient of the polynomial ring $C[x]$ by a polynomial of degree $n$ is always an $n$-dimensional vector space over $C$ (with $1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{n-1}$ as a basis). (I assume that by "C X C X C" you mean $C \times C \times C$, i.e., $C^3$.)

Comment: @Rob: the isomorphism here is presumably one of rings, given the tags. Mason, are you familiar with the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: We've worked with it a bit in class, but I honestly don't understand the ring version very well.

Comment: Here's one way to move toward the answer: what are all the homomorphisms $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^3 + 1) \to \mathbb{C}$ of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras? You should find that there are exactly three; use all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need the answer, but here it goes:
First notice that $x = -1$ is a root of $x^3 + 1$ and then you can divide $x^3 + 1$ by $x+1$ using your favorite method to obtain:

$$x^3 + 1 = (x+1)\left(x-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(x - \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$

Now notice that you wrote your polynomial as product of irreducible/prime elements, which means that the ideals $\langle x+1 \rangle$, $\left\langle x-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right\rangle$ and $\left\langle x - \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right\rangle$ are coprimes and you can use the Chinese remainder theorem to obtain:

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\langle x^3+1 \rangle} & = \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\left\langle (x+1)\left(x-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(x - \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right\rangle} \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\left\langle x+1\right\rangle \left\langle x-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right\rangle \left\langle x - \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right\rangle} \\
& \overset{CRT}{\cong} \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\langle x+1 \rangle} \times \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\left\langle x-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right\rangle} \times \frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{\left\langle x-\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right\rangle} \\
& \overset{ev}{\cong} \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}
\end{align}

Here $ev_{\alpha} : \mathbb{C}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ is the evaluation map, ie, $ev_{\alpha}(p(x)) = p(\alpha)$. Can you see that $ev_{\alpha}$ induces an isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x-\alpha \rangle$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I did eventually get it, I think my main problem was I just didn't remember the CRT at all. Thank you for the help thou, this will probably also help anybody else with a similar problem.

Comment: It's just practice. I also didn't remember until Qiaochu commented, but I did the general case for any polynomial once. Could you accept the answer?